# Javascript array iteration using for..in with MooTools included

Tags: javascript, mootools, for-in-loop

I am iterating over an array in MooTools but seeing additional items when iterating through the array using the shorthand `for..in` loop. It works fine when I use the regular `for` loop. Is this a problem with MooTools polluting the global namespace or am I doing something wrong here?

There is a `createTabs()` function that iterates over an array and creates a tab for each value in the array:

```
function createTabs() {
    var myTabs = [["First", "a.png"], ["Second", "b.png"]];
    for(var i in myTabs) {
        var tab = new Tab(myTabs[i][0], myTabs[i][1]);
        console.log(i);
    }
}
```

This is the output of `console.log(i)`:

```
0
1
$family
each
clean
associate
link
contains
extend
getLast
getRandom
include
combine
erase
empty
flatten
hexToRgb
rgbToHex
toJSON
```

I understand the first 2 indexes, but where is the rest coming from?

**Edit**: Thanks for the quick answers Chetan and k Prime. That makes sense, and the `Array.each` addition by MooTools is much cleaner way to iterate!

Looks a lot better now:

```
myTabs.each(function(item) {
    var tab = new Tab(item[0], item[1]);
    console.log(item);
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`for..in` is not meant for array iteration. It iterates over all the properties of an object that are not built-in. Since MooTools has added more functions to Array prototype, they are now array properties as well. See this https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Statements/For...in

Just use a basic for loop for array iteration.

Answer (score 9):

As Chetan pointed out, `for .. in` is meant for object property iteration, not arrays. however, you can iterate over the current members (and not the inherited members set by MooTools), by using `hasOwnProprty`, like so:

```
for (i in array)
    if (array.hasOwnProperty(i))
    {
        //.. do stuff ...
    }
```

Orr, better still, since you're using MooTools, just use the `Array.each` method:

```
array.each (function (item, index)
{
    // ... do stuff ...
});
```

Comment: It should be pointed out that function based iteration (e.g.: `array.each`) is much slower than a normal `for` or `for..in`

Comment: just a note that .each will be a standard browser feature soon as per ECMA and mootools checks if there is native support upon defining the alias for the function-based forEach to .each - hence the performance drop is only temporary and would mainly affect older browsers. i still would not recommend using for ... in for array walking unless you need the array keys (but it's still a hack)