# Conflicts in Mootools & jQuery In Joomla

Tags: javascript, jquery, conflict

I read all the related post but I think I am missing something.

My page structure is:

1 - Load Motools library in Joomla. Code:

```
JHTML::_('behavior.tooltip');
JHTML::_('behavior.mootools');
JHTML::_('behavior.formvalidation');
```

2 -  Then load the Jquery library  code is:

```
<script language="javascript" src="<?=$this->baseurl;?>/includes/js/jquery/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?=$this->baseurl;?>/includes/js/jquery/customjsfile.js"></script>`
```

3 - Then there are few JS function which uses Jquery Functionalities. The code is:

```
function abc() { /* -.stuffs uses jquery */ }
function xyz() { /* ..another function which uses jquery */}
```

4 -  Load body of the page

5 - At the end again few lines of JS code . Which again use Jquery. Code is:

```
<script language="javascript">
  $("#dialog").html(newHTML);
</script>
```

This is how my page is.
Now I am getting the Conflict errors in Motools & Jquery.

How do I resolve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `jQuery` instead of `$` and

give

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

**[jQuery.noConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)**

> Many JavaScript libraries use  $ as a
>   function or variable name, just as
>   jQuery does. In jQuery's case,  $ is
>   just an alias for jQuery, so all
>   functionality is available without
>   using  $. If we need to use another
>   JavaScript library alongside jQuery,
>   we can return control of  $ back to
>   the other library with a call to
>   $.noConflict():

Comment: I would Like to share thing here - 
the for-in loop returns some strange o/p.
But I managed to overcome it by first taking array.length in a variable then use the for loop to iterate over an array.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040042/javascript-array-iteration-using-for-in-with-mootools-included

Answer (score 1):

Please see:

[Using JQuery with other libraries.](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries)

Answer (score 1):

jQuery.noConflict(), this is what you need.

```
 <html>
 <head>
   <script src="prototype.js"></script>
   <script src="jquery.js"></script>
   <script>
     jQuery.noConflict();

     // Use jQuery via jQuery(...)
     jQuery(document).ready(function(){
       jQuery("div").hide();
     });

     // Use Prototype with $(...), etc.
     $('someid').hide();
   </script>
 </head>
 <body></body>
 </html>
```

source: http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries

Answer (score 0):

See this page. It seems to be answered there

http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-en/browse_thread/thread/3dabd31a8ab60505?pli=1