# Mootools is adding unwanted function calls to JSON results

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, mootools

I have a function that gets a list of vehicles in an asp.net page

```
 function GetVehicleCounts(totalVehicles, vehiclesInDepot, vehiclesInFilter,         vehiclesInKnownLocations, vehiclesInUnknownLocations, vehiclesNotInDepot)
{
vehiclesInDepot.value = 0;
vehiclesInFilter.value = 0;
vehiclesInKnownLocations.value = 0;
vehiclesInUnknownLocations.value = 0;
vehiclesNotInDepot.value = 0;
var listofVehicles;
var count = 0;

for (var k in vehicles_dm) {
    vehiclesInDepot.value++;

    if (vehicles_dm[k].IsInFilter) {
        vehiclesInFilter.value++;
    }

    if (vehicles_dm[k].CurrentFeatureType == 11) {
        vehiclesInUnknownLocations.value++;            
    }
    else {
        vehiclesInKnownLocations.value++;
    }
}

if (vehicles_dm != null) {
    vehiclesNotInDepot.value = totalVehicles - vehicles_dm.length;
}
}
```

However, when I add Mootools to the page I run into the problem of Mootools adding all the function calls to the results. This ends up getting repeated for any function that is similar. Any ideas for correcting?

I don't have a choice about using Mootools and the existing page is done in jQuery.

Comment: "adding all the function calls to the results" - this makes no sense, please elaborate

Comment: Yes, specifically _which_ function calls are being added?

Comment: Why is there an apostrophe at the end of the first function def? It is making the second function a string. Is that a typo just on SO or in your js file?

Comment: Also `GetVehiclesCallback` is not going to call `GetVehicles_Callback`...

Comment: I've experiences this before, basically mootools literally copies the code into the results. so if you had a function called bob(){some stuff} then a var called $result, $result would contain, $result = resultbob(){some stuff} it makes no sense. I couldnt find a fix

Comment: oh that's just rubbish. mootools does NOT add anything to your function. but mootools is prototypical. this means, your code is doing something unreasonable, like `for (var in [])` without a `hasOwnProperty` check, etc. post the actual code and the exception, even parts of the response along with the wrapper. even if you DO include mootools, it changes NOTHING on the Function prototype (other than polyfill .bind etc) and it certainly won't decorate any existing functions! `this.GetAllVehicleIds` -> inner reference to `this.ServiceUrl` without a bind - this is not your full code, is it?

Comment: No It's not the whole code since it's so large of a page/pages. As part of this page it's supposed to do a vehicle count and as soon as I added the include of mootools and again when I added the include of more-mootools it runs thru the ciount of vehicles, and then it adds the mootools functions within the count, each function being added as a new vehicle.

Comment: function GetVehicleCounts(totalVehicles, vehiclesInDepot, vehiclesInFilter, vehiclesInKnownLocations, vehiclesInUnknownLocations, vehiclesNotInDepot)
{
    vehiclesInDepot.value = 0;
    vehiclesInFilter.value = 0;
    vehiclesInKnownLocations.value = 0;
    vehiclesInUnknownLocations.value = 0;
    vehiclesNotInDepot.value = 0;
    var listofVehicles;
    var count = 0;

    for (var k in vehicles_dm) {
        vehiclesInDepot.value++;        if (vehicles_dm[k].IsInFilter) {
            vehiclesInFilter.value++;
        }

Comment: if (vehicles_dm[k].CurrentFeatureType == 11) {
            vehiclesInUnknownLocations.value++;            
        }
        else {
            vehiclesInKnownLocations.value++;
            listofVehicles += vehicles_dm[k].Id;

        }
        count++;
    }

    if (vehicles_dm != null) {
        vehiclesNotInDepot.value = totalVehicles - vehicles_dm.length;
    }
}

Comment: when the JSON serialization happens in any array it does this...

Comment: So when I look at the results I see vehicle 200 and then $family and so on and so on. but it's every single array...

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer!

'for..in is not meant for array iteration. It iterates over all the properties of an object that are not built-in. Since MooTools has added more functions to Array prototype, they are now array properties as well. See this https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Statements/For...in

Just use a basic for loop for array iteration.'

[Javascript array iteration using for..in with MooTools included](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040042/javascript-array-iteration-using-for-in-with-mootools-included)

Comment: quite, like i said in the comment - you are doing `for var in`.