# MooTools and Array prototype

Tags: javascript, arrays, prototypejs, mootools

Mootools is overridding the Array prototype, and the problem is that this prototype and I have an external .js (a library that I can't modify manually) that iterates using `for(i in someArray)` and it is throwing exception, since now Array has more properties. Any ideas of how to overcome this problem ?  I was thinking about removing those properties from array on the Mootools library itself, but it seems is not that easy.

Comment: If you can modify the libraries you are using, you should add `if (!someArray.hasOwnProperty(i)) continue;` in these for loops. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2040042/995958

Comment: `for(i in someArray) if (someArray.hasOwnProperty(i)) {/* your code */}`

Comment: Related: [Why is using “for…in” with array iteration a bad idea?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/4642212)

Comment: I know is a bad practice, but this is a javaScript file from built-in SharePoint, it is defined on the sp.ribbon.js to be more specific. Somebody in Microsoft had the idea to iterate on arrays in this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you should use a regular `for(var i=0; i < arr.length; i++) { var el = arr[i]; }` loop on arrays.

If you really need `for..in` and you are working in modern browsers, then you can modify the modification to the prototype to make it non-enumerable.

```js
//Logger function
function logArray(arr) {
    console.log("--TEST-START--");
    for (var i in arr) {
      console.log(arr[i])
    }
    console.log("--TEST-END--");
  }
  //Modify prototype
Array.prototype.a = {
  b: 0
};
//List to test against
var list = [1, 2, 3, 4];
//Log initial list
logArray(list);
//Modify prototype modificiation
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'a', {
  enumerable: false
});

//Log initial list
logArray(list);
```

Comment: Yes this is the right solution yet I would expect mootools to do this in the first place when they are adding new methods to the `Array.prototype()`.